How to check if a letter is an accent letter (pdflatex) - Problem with letters and diacritics when written in auxiliary file
I modified the sesamanuel class to suit my needs. This class originally compiles with xelatex but mine aim to compile with pdflatex and lualatex.
This class handle glossary(lexique).
\documentclass[nocrop,16pt]{sesamanuel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\MotDefinition{équilatéral}{} %write \crss@preinsertlexique []{équilatéral}{1} to .lex file
\MotDefinition{triangle}{} %write \crss@preinsertlexique []{triangle}{1} to .lex file
\AfficheLexique[2] % sort entries and display them

\end{document}

But when the first letter has an accent, the program never stop.
\newcommand*\AfficheLexique[1][\NombreColonneLexique]{%
  \clearpage
  \pagestyle{lexique}
  \thispagestyle{firstlexique}
  \vspace*{-5mm}
  \begingroup
  \columnsep \dimexpr \SquareWidth*2
  \columnseprule \LexiqueRuleWidth
  \def\columnseprulecolor{\color{LexiqueColumnRuleColor}}%
  \smc@numlexique \z@
  \begin{multicols}{#1}%
    % this is the first read of the .lex file that handle duplications
    \let\smc@insertlexique\smc@insertlexiqueinitial
    \let\smc@preinsertlexique\smc@preinsertlexiqueinitial
    \begingroup
      \makeatletter
      \@input{\jobname.lex}%
    \endgroup
    \let\smc@insertlexique\smc@insertlexiquefinal
    \let\smc@preinsertlexique\smc@preinsertlexiquefinal
    % then it actually compute .lex
    \@starttoc{lex}%
    \multido{\n=1+1}{\smc@numlexique}{%
      \expandafter\xdef\csname index\n\endcsname{\n}%
    }%
    \ifnum\smc@numlexique>\z@
      \smc@trifusion{1}{\the\smc@numlexique}%
      \def\smc@currentletter{A}%
      \multido{\n=1+1}{\smc@numlexique}{%
        \smc@afficheentree{\n}%
      }%
    \fi
  \end{multicols}
  \endgroup
}


It computes \@starttoc{lex}% but never stop.
How does the class made it work ?
In order to sort, the class transform é to e, è to e, à to a ... to do so, it check if \Iec is the first token
\long\def\smc@@FirstUppercase#1#2#3\@nil#4\@nil{%
  \def\smc@arg{#1}%
  \ifx\smc@arg\smc@IeC
    \expandafter\protected@xdef\csname lexique\the\smc@numlexique\endcsname
      {%
        \protect\textcolor{LexiqueEntreeColor}
          {%
            \protect\LexiqueEntreeFont
            \MakeUppercase{#1#2}%
            \MakeLowercase{#3}%
          }%
        \unexpanded{#4}%
      }%
  \else
    \expandafter\protected@xdef\csname lexique\the\smc@numlexique\endcsname
      {%
        \protect\textcolor{LexiqueEntreeColor}
          {%
            \protect\LexiqueEntreeFont
            \MakeUppercase{#1}%
            \MakeLowercase{#2#3}%
          }%
        \unexpanded{#4}%
      }%
  \fi
}

But there is no \Iec written in that .lex file.
How to make it work with pdflatex and lualatex please ?

since a few years utf8 chars are protected and so written as is to a file. The class should be adapted. Write the author.
